# cocos- 2d :How to scroll layer1 across parallax layer

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating game in cocos 2D .

I have two layers .layer one and layer two.

**layer 1 - large background (bg image size - 600 x 360) z:0 

Layer 2 - parallax layer (world size - 1200 x 360) z:1**

I just want background to scroll slightly when my layer 2 is moved .

What should i do to achieve the above thing?

should i set the **layer1** position to **sprite or layer2** postion so that layer 1 sync with layer 2.Any help or suggestion will be appreciated..

Comment: nice .. i am also looking for this. some one please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding a prallax layer to world size :)